# Does each operator $T: L^2 \to L^2$ with zero nullspace, have a continuous inverse?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Consider an operator $T: L^2 (\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is an open and bounded domain.

Let $T$ have a zero nullspace.

Questions. Does that imply that:

- $T$ continuous?
- $T^{-1}$ continuous?
- $\|Tx\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \geq C\| x\|_{L^2(\Omega)},\quad \forall x\in L^2(\Omega)$?

If so, can we sketch a proof?

Comment: Do you know it is bounded or maybe linear? Have you looked into the Open Mapping Theorem?

Comment: $T$ can be compact, then none of these claims hold

Comment: @daw May be except first claim? Is'nt a compact operator continuous by default? In fact they were earlier called as completely continous, if I am not wrong.

Comment: yes, you are right. Didnt pay attention to this first item.

Comment: @SescoMath: $T$ is linear and we can assume it is bounded (continuous).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, $L^2(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space, you can choose an orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}_{i\in \wedge}$. Using the Zorn's lemma one can extend this orthonormal basis to a Hamel basis $\{e_i\}_{i\in \wedge\cup\wedge_o}$. Now define a linear operator $T:L^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$ as $T(e_i)=e_i$ for all $i\in \wedge$ and $T(e_i)=2e_i$ for all $i\in \wedge_o$. This clearly a linear operator which is identity on a dense subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$. If it were to be continuous, it would extend uniquely to Identity operator. Hence, $T$ is not continuous although it is injective. It fails all other claims as well.

Now if you also impose the condition that $T$ is bounded(continuous) and have closed range, then by open mapping theorem you could conclude that $T^{-1}$ is continuous and $||Tx||\geq C||x||$

Comment: How about this for the third claim in my post. Assume $T$ is continuous. Futher, zero nullspace of $T$ implies that $Tx = 0$ only when $x=0$. Therefore $Tx \neq 0,\, \forall x \in L^2(\Omega)$, and so $\|Tx\|_{L^2(\Omega)} > 0$. Shouldn't there always exist a $C>0$ such that $\|Tx\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \geq C\, \| x\|_{L^2(\Omega)},\, \forall x \in L^2(\Omega)$, $x\neq 0$?

Comment: (I added a separate question about the comment above: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4799126/is-tx-l2c-x-l2-when-t-l2-to-l2-is-a-continuous-operator-wi )