# Is $\|Tx\|_{L^2}>C\|x\|_{L^2}$ when $T: L^2 \to L^2$ is a continuous operator with zero nullspace?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open and bounded domain.
Let $T: L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ be a continuous operator with zero nullspace.

Question.
Does it hold that $\|Tx\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \geq C\, \|x \|_{L_2(\Omega)}\, \forall x\in L^2(\Omega), x\neq 0$?

An attempt to show that the answer to the question above is "yes".

Zero nullspace of  implies that $Tx=0$ only when $x=0$. Therefore $Tx \neq 0$,$\forall x\in L^2(\Omega),\, x\neq 0$, and so $\|Tx\|_{L^2(\Omega)} > 0$. At the same time $\|x\|_{L^2(\Omega)}>0$ for $x\neq 0$. Thus there always exists $C>0$ such that $\|Tx\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \geq C\, \|x \|_{L_2(\Omega)}\, \forall x\in L^2(\Omega), x\neq 0$. Could there be something wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: Perhaps that $C$ is going to depend on $Tx$, i.e., $C=C(Tx)$, and then this lower bound is not so helpful?

Answer (score 4):

This holds with $C > 0$ if and only if the range of $T$ is closed.

For a simple counterexample, take $\Omega = (0,1)$ and let $T$ defined by
$$
(T x)(t) := t x(t).
$$

Comment: What if assume that $T$ is also self-adjoint?

Comment: "My" operator $T$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: But wouldn't a self-adjoint continuous $T: L^2 \to L^2$ with zero nullspace imply that its range is closed in $L^2$? Doesn't the third statement from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_range_theorem (Statements section), apply?

Comment: No, because this would require that $T$ is surjective. "My" $T$ only has a dense range.

Comment: But your T still fullfills the closed range theorem assumptions on T and the third statement from the link? If not, can you provide the point where it fails? That would be great for my learning.

Comment: No, the third statement is not satisfied. In fact, it is easy to check that the range of $T$ is not $L^2$. However, it is injective, thus the range has to be dense (due to self-adjointness). Consequently, the range cannot be closed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. If it would be true then any continuous operator $T:L^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$ with $\ker(T)=\{0\}$ would be invertible. Also, it would imply that if $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$, then $\lambda$ is not in the spectrum of $T$.